# Generics method signature

Tags: java, generics

I have 2 different maps of different types, both of which are subclasses of `BaseClass`.

I has hoping to be able to use the same logic for 'saving' an item to the map for both cases, using Generics.

assume `getId` is a method of `BaseClass`.

I need to force

1. the `item` to be a subclass of `BaseClass`
2. the `map` value to be the same type as the `item`

How can I do this? here is a failed attempt which kind of describes what I need to do:

```
private <T><?extends BaseClass> void save(T item, Map<Long, T> map)
{
    if (item.getId() == null)
    {
        long max = -1;
        for (Long key : map.keySet())
            max = Math.max(max, key);
        item.setId(max + 1);
    }
    map.put(item.getId(), item);
}
```

Comment: You're close. Replace `><?` by a space. I'm however unsure how the question title is related to this. This is very confusing.

Comment: @BalusC thanks, post your comment as an answer for the tick!

Comment: *the map value to be the same type as the item*.  Your code will enforce this as long as you mean that they have to be assignable to the same base type.  If however `BaseClass` was `Number` and `item` was an `Integer`, you would not be able to enforce that `map` is a `Map<Long, Integer>` since it could always be a `Map<Long, Number>` (in which case T is `Number`).  In fact, "[PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)" suggests that `map` should be a `Map<Long, ? super T>` since it shouldn't matter what exact type it is as long as you only need to add to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This part

```
<T><?extends BaseClass>
```

needs to be

```
<T extends BaseClass>
```

#### See also:

- [Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)